# How do I negate/invert a django-filter (exclude *unless* filter is active)?

Tags: django, django-filter

Given a filter set like this:

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    include_unusual_entries = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method='noop')
```

I would like the 'default' queryset to be

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(unusual_state=True)
```

and only if the `include_unusual_entries` filter is set, I would like it the queryset to be

```
MyModel.objects.all()
```

Am I missing an obvious way to solve this? I don't see a way to set `invert=True` on a filter, or a way to set `always_filter` so that I could put an if into the `method`.

---

For now, I solved it by overriding the `qs` property on my filter set, but it feels pretty wrong:

```
@property
def qs(self):
    queryset = super(MyFilter, self).qs
    if 'include_unusual_entries' in self.data:   # if inclusion is explcitly enabled
        return queryset
    else:   # if inclusion is *not* explicitly enabled (the default)
        return queryset.exclude(unusual_state=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've left my original answer below, but a much simpler option is to combine a `method` with `CheckboxInput`, which does not distinguish empty from false. In effect, it defaults to false unless otherwise specified. This is one of the few instances where `CheckboxInput` is actually appropriate.

```py
class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    include_unusual_entries = filters.BooleanFilter(
        method='filter_unusual_entries',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput,
    )

    def filter_unusual_entries(self, qs, name, value):
        return qs if value else qs.exclude(unusual_state=True)
```

---

This is a bit of an unusual case. Filtering is generally a subtractive process, but here it's additive. While your current solution may feel clunky, it is 
valid. The only change I would make, would be to extract the value from the form's `cleaned_data` instead of from the unprocessed `data` query dict.

```py
if self.cleaned_data.get('include_unusual_entries', False):
    return queryset
```

That said, a few alternative solutions:

#### Force a default value

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from django_filters.constants import EMPTY_VALUES


class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    include_unusual_entries = filters.BooleanFilter(method='filter_unusual_entries')

    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if data is not None:  # if filterset is bound, force default value
            data = data.copy()  # get a mutable copy of the QueryDict

            if data.get('include_unusual_entries', None) in EMPTY_VALUES:
                data['include_unusual_entries'] = False

        super().__init__(data, *args, **kargs)

    def filter_unusual_entries(self, name, qs, value):
        return qs if value else qs.exclude(unusual_state=True)
```

#### Similar, but with `filter_queryset()`

Overriding the `.qs` property has always been a bit awkward. Although it's still in development, django-filter 2.x addresses this. You would instead override `filter_queryset()`.

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from django_filters.constants import EMPTY_VALUES


class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    include_unusual_entries = filters.BooleanFilter(method='noop')

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        if not self.form.cleaned_data.get('include_unusual_entries', False):
            queryset = queryset.exclude(unusual_state=True)
        return super().filter_queryset(queryset)
```

Comment: Thank you for your edit, I like that new first solution better indeed! I think there was a typo, the parameters in your example are in the wrong order. I've submitted an edit request.

Comment: Thanks for fixing - I wasn't sure if you'd get a notification for the updated answer.

Comment: I actually wasn't, but found your edit when I went back to implement one of your solutions.